# Add Text Value to a Userform TextBox if Checkbox value if statement is TRUE

Tags: excel, vba, checkbox, textbox, userform

I have a userform to update my currency analysis sheets.  I have a checkbox on the top right that will dictate whether the date from date picker is holiday or not.  If it is (meaning the checkbox is checked and therefore TRUE, then all of the textboxes will become a value of "HOL".  If unchecked (or FALSE) the the textboxes will be a value of blank and I can enter the daily numbers before clicking the Submit command button to send to the sheets.  Of course I would like the HOL to be the value sent to the sheets if the Checkbox value is TRUE.  Please help...thanks in advance.  The Check box name is HOLIDAY.

Here is the userform

[Daily entry userform](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XdkVW.jpg)

and Here is the code

```
Private Sub HOLIDAY_Click()
    If Me.HOLIDAY.Value = True Then
    Me.DTPicker1.Value = "HOL"
    Me.JP_Open.Value = "HOL"
    Me.JP_Hi.Value = "HOL"
    Me.JP_Lo.Value = "HOL"
    Me.JP_Close.Value = "HOL"
    Me.CAD_Open.Value = "HOL"
    Me.CAD_Hi.Value = "HOL"
    Me.CAD_Lo.Value = "HOL"
    Me.CAD_Close.Value = "HOL"
    Me.GBP_Open.Value = "HOL"
    Me.GBP_Hi.Value = "HOL"
    Me.GBP_Lo.Value = "HOL"
    Me.GBP_Close.Value = "HOL"
    Me.Swiss_Open.Value = "HOL"
    Me.Swiss_Hi.Value = "HOL"
    Me.Swiss_Lo.Value = "HOL"
    Me.Swiss_Close.Value = "HOL"
    Me.AUD_Open.Value = "HOL"
    Me.AUD_Hi.Value = "HOL"
    Me.AUD_Lo.Value = "HOL"
    Me.AUD_Close.Value = "HOL"
    Me.Euro_Open.Value = "HOL"
    Me.Euro_Hi.Value = "HOL"
    Me.Euro_Lo.Value = "HOL"
    Me.Euro_Close.Value = "HOL"
    Me.EURJPY_Open.Value = "HOL"
    Me.EURJPY_Hi.Value = "HOL"
    Me.EURJPY_Lo.Value = "HOL"
    Me.EURJPY_Close.Value = "HOL"
    Me.AUDNZD_Open.Value = "HOL"
    Me.AUDNZD_Hi.Value = "HOL"
    Me.AUDNZD_Lo.Value = "HOL"
    Me.AUDNZD_Close.Value = "HOL"
    Me.EURNZD_Open.Value = "HOL"
    Me.EURNZD_Hi.Value = "HOL"
    Me.EURNZD_Lo.Value = "HOL"
    Me.EURNZD_Close.Value = "HOL"
    Me.NZDCAD_Open.Value = "HOL"
    Me.NZDCAD_Hi.Value = "HOL"
    Me.NZDCAD_Lo.Value = "HOL"
    Me.NZDCAD_Close.Value = "HOL"
    Me.NZDUSD_Open.Value = "HOL"
    Me.NZDUSD_Hi.Value = "HOL"
    Me.NZDUSD_Lo.Value = "HOL"
    Me.NZDUSD_Close.Value = "HOL"
    Me.NZDJPY_Open.Value = "HOL"
    Me.NZDJPY_Hi.Value = "HOL"
    Me.NZDJPY_Lo.Value = "HOL"
    Me.NZDJPY_Close.Value = "HOL"
    Me.GBPJPY_Open.Value = "HOL"
    Me.GBPJPY_Hi.Value = "HOL"
    Me.GBPJPY_Lo.Value = "HOL"
    Me.GBPJPY_Close.Value = "HOL"
Else
    Me.DTPicker1.Value = ""
    Me.JP_Open.Value = ""
    Me.JP_Hi.Value = ""
    Me.JP_Lo.Value = ""
    Me.JP_Close.Value = ""
    Me.CAD_Open.Value = ""
    Me.CAD_Hi.Value = ""
    Me.CAD_Lo.Value = ""
    Me.CAD_Close.Value = ""
    Me.GBP_Open.Value = ""
    Me.GBP_Hi.Value = ""
    Me.GBP_Lo.Value = ""
    Me.GBP_Close.Value = ""
    Me.Swiss_Open.Value = ""
    Me.Swiss_Hi.Value = ""
    Me.Swiss_Lo.Value = ""
    Me.Swiss_Close.Value = ""
    Me.AUD_Open.Value = ""
    Me.AUD_Hi.Value = ""
    Me.AUD_Lo.Value = ""
    Me.AUD_Close.Value = ""
    Me.Euro_Open.Value = ""
    Me.Euro_Hi.Value = ""
    Me.Euro_Lo.Value = ""
    Me.Euro_Close.Value = ""
    Me.EURJPY_Open.Value = ""
    Me.EURJPY_Hi.Value = ""
    Me.EURJPY_Lo.Value = ""
    Me.EURJPY_Close.Value = ""
    Me.AUDNZD_Open.Value = ""
    Me.AUDNZD_Hi.Value = ""
    Me.AUDNZD_Lo.Value = ""
    Me.AUDNZD_Close.Value = ""
    Me.EURNZD_Open.Value = ""
    Me.EURNZD_Hi.Value = ""
    Me.EURNZD_Lo.Value = ""
    Me.EURNZD_Close.Value = ""
    Me.NZDCAD_Open.Value = ""
    Me.NZDCAD_Hi.Value = ""
    Me.NZDCAD_Lo.Value = ""
    Me.NZDCAD_Close.Value = ""
    Me.NZDUSD_Open.Value = ""
    Me.NZDUSD_Hi.Value = ""
    Me.NZDUSD_Lo.Value = ""
    Me.NZDUSD_Close.Value = ""
    Me.NZDJPY_Open.Value = ""
    Me.NZDJPY_Hi.Value = ""
    Me.NZDJPY_Lo.Value = ""
    Me.NZDJPY_Close.Value = ""
    Me.GBPJPY_Open.Value = ""
    Me.GBPJPY_Hi.Value = ""
    Me.GBPJPY_Lo.Value = ""
    Me.GBPJPY_Close.Value = ""

End If
End Sub
```

If you need more information or more of my code.  Thanks in advance once again.

I have now used this code and it does allow me to click the checkbox and add HOL to all fields...but I receieve an error when trying to clear the text boxes or close the userform.

```
Private Sub Holiday_Click()

Dim ctrl As Control

With Me

    For Each ctrl In .Controls
        If TypeName(ctrl) = "TextBox" And .HOLIDAY = True Then
            ctrl.Value = "HOL"
                End If
   Next ctrl
End With

End Sub
```

I had to modify the original code to exclude the ELSE statement that said

```
Else
ctrl.Value = ""
```

because it would error out.

Comment: With that many variables you should consider a loop reading an array of constants. Otherwise I'd consider it "ugly programming".
Also please read: **https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve**

Comment: Thank you...but you you lost me on that one.  Can you please clarify?

Comment: It's still unclear what your problem is! What is your problem? Your question is not complete! (see https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: D Brown, did you  read https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve ?

Comment: @simple-solution  My goal is to populate all of the textbox fields of the userform with "HOL" so that they can be sent via the SUBMIT button that I created to the spreadsheets if it is a holiday.  If not then the fields remain blank for user input of those values which will then be sent  via the SUBMIT button that I created to the spreadsheets.

Comment: `Else if TypeName(ctrl) = "TextBox" then ctrl.Value = ""`

Comment: What is the error message you get?

Comment: @simple-solution THANK YOU!!!!  You have truly helped me.  The error was a compile error.  But with this modification you just provided me it works perfectly.  Thank you again!!!